# Intuition for continuous compound interest

Tags: compound-interest

The formula for continuos compound interest is
$$A = Pe^{(rt)}$$
Where $r$ is the interest rate per year.
Interestingly, even though the money is compounded continuosly , it still depends on the annual interest rate rather than instantaneous interest rate. Is there any intuition to understand this?

Comment: What's "instantaneous" interest rate?

Comment: This is the essence of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867020/continuous-vs-annual-compound-interest). Regardless how we call $r$ (we can get to that later) do you know how the formula $e^{rt}$ comes about? Hint: Leonhard Euler.

Comment: Hint II: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{rt}{n})^n=e^{rt}\,,$ or if you like,
$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt}=e^{rt}\,.$

Comment: Suppose $t=1$ (one year) and $n=365$ (daily, that is almost continuously, compounding): what do the amounts $(1+\frac{r}{n}),(1+\frac{r}{n})^2,...$ represent economically ? If you do not join the discussion I will vote to close that question. We have to understand what we are doing and not just ask what "annual", "instantaneous" and "continuous" means.

Comment: @KurtG. I apologize responding so late. I guess they represent the amount present at the end of each day?

Comment: Exactly. The interest you receive each day is $\frac{r}{n}$ because there is a convention to quote every interest rate $r$ as an annual***ized*** rate. To call it annual is quite misleading. The fact that you receive that rate in almost every instant (daily or even more frequently) allows to call it *instantaneous*. That is not a contradiction. Just names.

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! You really made my day!

Answer (score 0):

For a principal $P$ and an annual rate of interest $r$ (compounded annually), the amount at the end of $t$ years is given by

$$A = P(1 + r)^t$$

**Part 1**

Before we move ahead, it's important to understand the meaning and significance of the phrase "compounded annually". The phrase implies that at the end of every *year* (because "annually"), we will take the amount at that point (principal at the start of that *year* + interest accrued during that *year*) and make it the principal for the next *year*.

If it said *compounded semi-annually*, it would imply that the end of every *six months*, we will take the amount at that point (principal at the start of that *six-month* period + interest accrued during that *six-month* perios) and make it the principal for the next *six months*.

Notice something? **Frequency of compounding has nothing to do with the rate of interest.** It just determines how often we will revise the principal (by adding interest to it) for the calculation of subsequent interests.

I hope this removes any doubts you had about why we are using the annual interest rate even when compounding continuously.

In our formula though (from above), $r$ will be replaced by $r/n$, where $n$ represents the number of times compounding in done every year. Why, you might ask? That's because the period for which we are calculating the interest is $1/n$ years.

As an example, if rate of interest is $10 \%$ and compounding is done semi-annually, the interest for each period would would only be $10 / 2 = 5$ percent because our *period* is only half a year.

So our formula becomes

$$A = P \left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt}$$

**Part 2**

Higher the frequency of compounding, the faster your interest starts earning interest. That, in turn, would mean a higher amount at the end of a year or $t$ years.

But how high can we go? What is the maximum amount we can obtain by reducing the period of compounding only (leaving the interest rate unchanged)? Well, the best we can do (at least, theoretically) is compound an infinite number of times. So make $n$ approach $\infty$. That would give us an amount of

$$\begin{align*}
A &= \lim_{n\to\infty} P \left( 1 + \frac{r}{n} \right)^{nt} \\[0.3cm]
&= Pe^{rt}
\end{align*}$$

Which, not surprisingly, is the formula you have in your post.

**To conclude**, the rate of interest and the frequency of compounding are two different things with nothing to do with one another. And the formula you mention is concerned only with the former.

Comment: So when the frequency of compounding changes, the  interest rate for the corresponding period also changes accordingly, i.e., gets reduced to r/n. Is that right?

Comment: Right. But to avoid any confusion, let me use an example. Say, the interest rate is $12 \%$ per annum. So what is your interest rate per month? $1 \%$, right? I hesitate to say the rate changes. Instead, I would say it is recalculated for the shorter period. $12 \%$ per annum is the same as $1 \%$ per month or $3 \%$ per quarter. Makes sense?

Comment: If we didn't do the recalculation and went with $r$ even for shorter periods, then, effectively, we would be changing the rate. Something we don't want.

Comment: Yes , it makes sense. Thank you so much for your clarification.